# Video orientation using ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

How to get video orientation using ffmpeg? I am using ffmpeg on android.

It seems ffmpeg not taking care automatically, in android lower versions I could not find api, so trying using ffmpeg. In android there is metadataretriver but it's api level is 17.
Please suggest way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the syntax of the transpose filter? For instance, to rotate the input by 90 degrees counter-clockwise:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "transpose=1" output
```

If not, could you detail your request a little bit more?